# Javascript -- How to find and replace text matched via nested array list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find text in all `<p>` tags, in document and replace the text if it is present in my search_array list:

```
search_array=[
                ['DBCONERROR01','Unable to Connect Database Server'],
                ['DBCONERROR02','Error Occured With DataBase Connection'],
                ['DBCONERROR03','Unable to Communicate with Data Base'],
                ['DBQRYERROR01','Invalid Query OR DataBase Error'],
                ['DBCONERROR04','Connection Lost with Database'],
                ['DBQRYERROR02','DataBase Query Failed'],
                ['DBQRYERROR03','Invalid to Wrong Sql Query'],
                ['TARIFERROR01','No Rates Found for Tariff'],
                ['AUTHSERROR01','Authentications not Found'],
                ['SWICHERROR01','Unable to Find Switch Details'],
                ['IOPRMERROR01','File Permission Error'],
                ['IOPRMERROR01','IO Error with operation System'],
                ['IOPRMERROR01','File Handling Error - Unable to Communicate with IO'],
                ['OPSSHERROR01','Unable to SSH switch - Connection Error'],
                ['OPSSHERROR02','SSH to Switch Failed'],
                ['OPSSHERROR03','Unable to Copy Scripts to Switch'],
                ['OPSSHERROR04','Unable to Execute Script on Switch'],
                ['JSONPERROR01','Unable to Parse Json'],
                ['TARIFERROR02','No Entry Found'],
                ['TARIFERROR03','Unable to Push Rates TO SBC'],
                ["DoesNotExist('Email does not exist.',)",'No Emails Received']
            ]
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            for(var i=0; i<search_array.length+1; i++)
                {
                    console.log(i);
                    console.log(search_array.length);
                    for(var j=0; j<search_array[i].length; j++)
                    {
                        var str = $("p").text();
                        console.log(str[0]);
                        str.replace(search_array[j], search_array[j+1]);
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is what my code looks like, But I am still unable to perform task... Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is you don't reset the `p` elements' textContent, also  `.replace()` method leaves the original string unchanged. You can use the `text()` method callback function, the callback is executed once for each selected element in the collection:

```
// var search_array = [ ... ];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').text(function(_, text) {
       for (var i = 0; i < search_array.length; i++) {
           text = text.replace(search_array[i][0], search_array[i][1]);
       }; 
       return text; // return the modified textContent
    });
});
```

Comment: What if I want to search in `<p>` if it contains more than one errors like: "DBCONERROR01, DBCONERROR04 was/were the reason(s) due to which task could not be performed!"

Comment: @user3149111 Well, we are using a `for` loop for iterating through the entire array for each `p` element, have you tried it? Does it fail? If yes!, can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

@BlackShape answers little bit modified version as following using each function:

```
// var search_array = [ ... ];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').text(function(_, text) {
       $.each(search_array, function(index){
          text = text.replace(search_array[index][0], search_array[index][1]);    
       }); 
       return text; // return the modified textContent
    });
});
```

Another drawback in @BlackShape's approach is `search_array.length` read multiple times inside for statement. If you want to use @BlackShape you can just read only one time and assign to local variable and use it inside of for loop statement.

```
for (var i = 0; i < search_array.length; i++)
```

Comment: Why isn't it efficient? Doesn't `$.each()` use `for` loops? https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L298

Comment: Every time reading arrays length in for loop. Is it good approach?

Comment: Sorry I mean different thing.

Comment: I see what you mean, but if the performance is the key I wouldn't use `$.each()`.

Comment: Why? Do you think performance of $.each is less than for loop?

Comment: Yes, `$.each` itself uses `for` loops.

Comment: Evidence of performance lake? However if you see your link in first comment you can see they reading array length only one time not multiple times. I just suggest to avoid that.

Comment: Well. Yes, why not? That's indeed a good suggestion for giant arrays. http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-each-vs-for-loop

Comment: Good evidence. Happy new year.